# Изменить цвет строк в DataGridView

Tags: c#, mysql

Пытаюсь изменить цвет строки там где значение penalty = 1.

```
MySqlConnection sqlConnection2 = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand();
MySqlDataReader reader2;
cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT librarycardnumber, fullname, adress, phone, penalty FROM Readers";
cmd2.Connection = sqlConnection2;
sqlConnection2.Open();
reader2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
if (reader2.Read())
{
    int penalty = reader2.GetInt32(4);

        if (penalty == 1)
                   dataGridView1.Rows[0].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                else
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
}
sqlConnection2.Close();
```

Сейчас она меняет цвет только первой строке, как сделать, чтобы она меняла цвет только там где значение penalty = 1?

Comment: Это действительно весь код?  Считанное из БД значение `penalty` не вставляется в `DataGridView`.

Comment: Пройдите циклом по всем строкам грида.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут идет обращение к Row[Idex] = 0

```
dataGridView1***.Rows[0]***.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

сделать цикл и подставлять Row[Idex] == № строки

//код для примера

```
   for (int i = 0; dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1; i++)
        {
         dataGridView1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
         }
```